# Java method reference for map - IntelliJ warning

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Intellij warns that this expression:

```
usersAttributes.get(user.getName()).forEach((attrName, val) -> user.addAttribute(attrName, val));
```

can be replaced by method reference. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ is right. You can rewrite that:

```
usersAttributes.get(user.getName()).forEach(user::addAttribute);
```

This kind of [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is called ["Reference to an instance method of a particular object"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#object):

> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of a particular object:
>
> ```
> class ComparisonProvider {
>      public int compareByName(Person a, Person b) {
>          return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
>      }
>
>      public int compareByAge(Person a, Person b) {
>          return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
>      }
>  }
>  ComparisonProvider myComparisonProvider = new ComparisonProvider();
>  Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, myComparisonProvider::compareByName);
> ```
>
> The method reference `myComparisonProvider::compareByName` invokes the method `compareByName` that is part of the object `myComparisonProvider`. The JRE infers the method type arguments, which in this case are `(Person, Person)`.

In your case, `user::addAttribute` refers to the method called `addAttribute` taking two parameters where the first is compatible with the type of `attrName` and the second is also compatible with the type of `val`. This method will be invoked on the `user` instance.